# Which model to use when dual-seasonality is present?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, multiple-seasonalities

I have an hourly time series that contains 2 forms of seasonality: hourly and weekly. In other words, the hour of the day and the day of the week both have a large impact on the time series values.

Is there a forecasting model (hopefully a pre-built one in R) that can handle a time series with multiple seasonalities?

One R function I have tried was auto.arima with xreg being a day-of-week indicator matrix.

Comment: https://otexts.org/fpp2/complexseasonality.html

Answer (score 1):

We have a tag [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), you may want to browse through it.

Standard models include [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) and [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats). Take a look at their tag wikis for more information and pointers to literature.